# Is storing a logged in user's role in vuex safe/best practice?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, vuex, roles

I'm using Firebase for authentication and setting up custom claims to handle roles/authorization.  It is a very typical app with 2 roles:  'admin', 'viewer'.

My plan is to add an 'admin' custom claim to new users on signup.  Then admins can add a user with role 'viewer' within the app, which will call a firebase function to set the 'viewer' custom claim.

When users login I will read their claim and store the value as either {role: 'admin'} or {role: 'viewer'} in the vuex store.

Later in my app I plan to check the role with a getter and hide/show different elements of the UI based on if the user is an admin or not.  I also use vuex-persistedstate plugin to save the store in local storage.

Does this all seem like a good plan?  Are there any security issues with storing -> role: 'admin' in vuex.  Or is this a standard app architecture?

Thanks.

Comment: If you've implemented security at service level, I think it should not be a problem. Firebase Client SDKs stores Authentication data in the browser, which you can inspect anyway.

Comment: Whether you show or hide UI doesn't affect security in any way. It cannot cause any security issues. Whether it's 'best' practice or not always depends on the case, this is the reason why opinion-based questions are prohibited on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It would not matter whether you store this information in Vuex or any other state management system. Firebase SDK Authentication already exposes this information within a *token* in client browser.

You should access custom claims in your Cloud Functions and establish if the user is authorized or not for such task. Also, a great plan would be using Security Rules with custom claims to protect your services.